# How to search set of specific pattern string using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I want to search a set of specific string from a word using PHP regular expression. The pattern is like this

1. The string is of 6 character length
2. First 5 characters of this string are number 0-9
3. Last 1 character is a A-Z or a-z alphabets
4. there are more then one strings like this in a Word.

So eg. the word is

```
037165L_55084L_1959Z
```

Then the output of regular expression should return below 2 strings

```
37165L
55084L
```

Comment: sorry, its updated now. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just use this regex in `preg_match_all` function:

```
\d{5}[a-zA-Z]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qG3xI2/1)

Comment: This doesn't meet #4 requirement ;)

Comment: It does meet that requirement due to my suggestion of `preg_match_all` function :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use this function**

```
    $string="your_character"
    $string = str_replace('your_character',' ',$string);
echo  $string;
```

Eg..

```
$string="037165L_55084L_1959Z"
    $string = str_replace('_55084L_1959Z',' ',$string);
echo  $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
 /([0-9]{5}[A-Za-z]).*([0-9]{5}[A-Za-z])/
```